# Why can't I access website on local machine using its internal/private IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, port-forwarding

I'm running a web app on port 8000 on my Mac. My mac's internal IP is 192.168.0.6. I can reach this web app using localhost:8000 and 192.168.0.6:8000

If I set up port forwarding on my router, forwarding all requests on port 80 to port 8000 on my Mac (192.168.0.6:8000), I can still reach the website using my public IP.

However, if I try to reach the website using my mac's internal IP on port `8000` (`192.168.0.6:8000`) from another computer on my local network (another Mac or iPad), I don't see the desired result and eventually the connection just times out.

I have an arris router at home.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you connecting to port :80 or port :8000 in the latter case?

Comment: @grawity port 8000 when trying to hit it with the internal IP

Comment: How are your firewalls configured, on the host running the web-site, and on the client trying to access it?

Comment: @AFH both client and host are Macbook Pros with the firewall disabled. Also I'm able to hit the website using my public and port-forwarding, so I doubt its a problem with the firewall settings on the Macs.

Comment: If it's not either of the firewalls, then it may be the web-site hosting software configuration. Can you use loop-back (ie use the public IP from within your intranet)? If so, then you may need to use WireShark (or a Mac equivalent) to compare the traffic between using the public and local IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my router and it is working fine (as expected) now.